# Is there a documentation on Hibernate's event types?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm normally really hesitant to post a question like this but I seem to be unable to find anything usable: *Is there any documentation on the Hibernate events, i.e. what the events mean, when they are thrown, what data they contain etc.?*

Any hint or link would be greatly appreciated.

To get a list of events I can just have a look at `org.hibernate.event.spi.EventType` and from that class I can get the actual event classes. However, the documentation on those classes is quite sparse and the hibernate user manual or developer guide don't provide anything either (just how to register listeners but that's actually simple).

I already tried to add listeners that just log when they are called but the output order is somewhat confusing and I making assumptions on what is called when is quite hard.

**Attention**: the following example might seem quite long and abstract and is an attempt to illustrate my problem. I'm only talking about 2 events here while there are 33 more which seem as undocumented.

There are 2 listeners:

- PreloadEventListener - JavaDoc says `Called before injecting property values into a newly loaded entity instance.`
- LoadEventListener - JavaDoc says `Defines the contract for handling of load events generated from a session.`

As you can see, the JavaDoc doesn't provide much information, at least for `LoadEventListener`. Both events might actually refer to different situations but as I already said, I couldn't find any documentation on that.

The listeners are also not always called in the same order it seems. 
I added both listeners to one of our existing web applications made some clicks.

Here are the results (abstracted output):

Action 1 output

```
preload: entity of type A with id 0
```

Action 2 output

```
preload: entity of type A with id 1
load: entity of type A with id 1
preload: entity of type B with id 0
```

Action 3 output

```
preload: entity of type C  with id 0
load:    entity of type D  with id 0
load:    entity of type E  with id 0
load:    entity of type F  with id 0
load:    entity of type A  with id 0
preload: entity of type F' with id 0
preload: entity of type A  with id 0
load:    entity of type C  with id 0
...
load:    entity of type A  with id 0
load:    entity of type C  with id 0
```

Describing what we're doing in those actions would be out of scope but as you can see we're mostly loading simple entities and a more complex structure in action 3.

As you can see sometimes only the preload event is triggered (e.g. `A` in action 1), sometimes there's only a load (e.g. `F` in action 3), sometimes there are multiple load events following a preload (e.g. `C` in action 3) or even alternating load and preload events (e.g. `A` in action 3).

`F'` would be a subclass of `F` which might explain the preload of `F'` after the load of `F` but the other cases are not that easily explained. I'm sure there is a deterministic order and a reason for some events not being called but as I initially said, I'm missing the documentation for that.

For all who read that "short" example: I hope it doesn't confuse you too much. If needed I can provide a more specfic example maybe even a simpler one, but I have a feeling that those simpler examples yield easier to explain results while our more complex real world cases are still not well understood. As I said I'm looking for some documentation of the 35 Hibernate event types rather than a detailed explanation of the depicted case.

Comment: I don't think you'll get a doc that explain when they are thrown etc, but here at least a list of them : http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/hibernate/core/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/event/EventListeners.java

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard thanks for the link, but as I already stated I have the sources as well as the list of event types, so basically I _could_ dig through the entire source and try to extract the information myself - which is tedious and most likely I'll miss something.

Comment: @ those who casted a close vote: I know that I'm basically asking for an "off-site resource" but I'm not sure the general description of the reason matches the question. I described what I tried and don't ask for opinions, but instead I need information on a _specific_ programming problem (when Hibernate will throw which event). Since this is still debatable please be at least so kind and give a short explanation why you still feel it's off-topic so that I can learn. :) Is it just because I ask for documentation - if there is any?

Comment: @Thomas did you find any other documentation? I am looking for it too and have found nothing so far.

Comment: @QutubDahodwala unfortunately not. If you find anything I'd apreciate you reporting it back here.